# Setting and checking Cookie with PHP not working in Safari

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, safari

I am having a really weird issue.. I am trying to set a cookie, and it works perfectly fine in all browsers except for Safari, both desktop and iOS Safari.

The weird thing is that I can see that it is being set because in Safari's inspector it shows the cookie as it should.

When I try to access the cookie using `$_COOKIE["wpcode"]` it does not show it, but in other browsers it does...

Going a step further, doing `print_r($_COOKIE)` does not display ANY cookies, though in my cookie panel there are a bunch of cookies set.

I am using Safari 8, but the issue occurs on all versions of Safari that I have tested (6.2+)

I am using WPEngine as a host, and I am using WordPress as well.

The code I am using to set my cookie is (but I have tried it every possible way I have found):

```
setcookie("wpcode", md5("true"), time()+60*60*24*7,"/", "", false);
```

I am trying to access the cookie like:

```
$_COOKIE["wpcode"] != md5("true")
```

Though I have tried everything like:

```
isset($_COOKIE["wpcode"])
```

This must obviously be an issue with Safari, I have looked through every page in Google regarding similar issues with no results...

Thanks!

Comment: See if this helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586863/safari-cookie-issue

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried this before and it didn't help any.. :\

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for being late to the party but I just ran into this issue myself. Turns out that WP Engine's aggressive caching makes retrieving cookies via php difficult / impossible.

[WP Engine - Cookies and PHP Sessions](https://wpengine.com/support/cookies-and-php-sessions/)

Looks like I'll need to use .js  I hope despite my tardiness this answer gives you some closure.