# Clearing Cookie with PHP behaves strange in Safari

Tags: javascript, php, ios, cookies, safari

I delete a cookie in PHP with the following code:

```
setcookie('test', null, -1, '/');
```

It works very well in all browsers, except in Safari. Subsequent requests from Safari send this Cookie to the webserver, if done fast enough.

Simplest example i could think of:

```
<?php

setcookie('test', null, -1, '/');
print_r( $_COOKIE );

?>
```

Hit F5 quickly in the browser. Sometimes you will see the cookie with the value deleted. The Platform seems not to matter. I get this result on iPhone, Safari (Windows) and Safari (Mac). For me it looks like a Safari bug, but maybe i'm missing something here?

I want the cookie never to be set in following requests, no matter how quick. Thanks for any insights.

Comment: I may have stumbled upon the same issue. What happens is that our web app sometimes gets requests where the cookie value is "deleted" (which is the value PHP sets a cookie to when you delete it). Apart from the Safaris you mentioned, sometimes the user agent seems to be Googlebot.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the problem?  I'm running into the exact same situation.  It only happens for a small number of our users, but it happens consistently to certain users, almost all on older versions of Safari.  Haven't been able to reproduce it in-house yet on any tested version of OSX and Safari.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was already reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586863/safari-cookie-issue).

The solution by setting the path:

```
setcookie('testcookie', 'cookiesetting temporary', time()+3600, '/path/'); // set 
setcookie('testcookie', '', time()-3600, '/path/'); // delete
```

Comment: I think this is a different issue. In my example the cookie is bein deleted, just not instantly. Besides i've tried to move the script into /test/ folder and adjusted the path accordingly. Still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you correctly setting the path in the fourth parameter ?

[safari cookie issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586863/safari-cookie-issue)

Comment: I need the cookie to be valid for the whole domain, hence / as path. Something wrong with that? Just following the [official reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) here.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. Here's how I solved it,
When setting and deleting the cookie **set the path and domain**

```php
setcookie("test_cookie", "test value", time() + 3600, "path", "domain");  // set cookie
setcookie("test_cookie", "", time() - 3600, "path", "domain");  // delete cookie
```